# URL.Page returns null for ASP.Core Identity

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an ASP.Core application. I have added Identity. I have then customized it I have copied the existing logic to send a verification e-mail to another model that resides in a different directory.

The auto generated scripts created an Areas/Identity directory. Underneath that directory, there is Pages/Account/Manage/Index.cshtml.cs file. The code in this folder uses the same call to generate the confirmation email code. It works fine.

However the custom model returns null when I call the Url.Page. I am not sure why. Below is how I am customizing the Identity in startup.cs

```
services.AddIdentity<WebUser, WebRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyIdentityDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddDefaultUI();
```

This is the place where it breaks when it tries to get the Page location using the existing Identity framework. The Url.Page returns null.

```
var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
var email = await _userManager.GetEmailAsync(user);
var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                 "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                 pageHandler: null,
                 values: new { userId = userId, code = code },
                 protocol: Request.Scheme);
await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(
                email,
                "Confirm your email",
                $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");
```

Why does calling the URL.Page from a different model create such a difference? I am guessing I am missing something rudimentary on how routing works but not sure what.

Comment: What do you mean **However sometimes**? Could you reproduce this issue with specific action and user account? It seems there is no error for these code. Why did you create it manually, I suggest you try Right Click Project->Add-> New Scaffold Item->Identity to generate the required files.

Comment: I have created the code automatically using dotnet add identity command line but I have copied this code to be used elsewhere which does not fall within the same directory structure. Hence the automated code generation works but when I use it copied in another module that does not live within the same directory structure, it does not.

Answer (score 13):

That's due to the fact. The scaffolded identity uses a different area called identity so to call it from a different location, you have to add to the

```
values= new {area = "Identity", userId = userId, code = code}
```

[See this link on stackoverflow for more information.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30341268/how-to-pass-area-in-url-action)

Comment: Woking in Asp.Net Core 2.0 - 2.2

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. Worked for me in Asp.Net Core 2.2

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem until I realize that I didn't have the `ConfirmEmail.cshtml` and `ConfirmEmail.cshtml.cs` on my project.
To add only these files from scaffold run the following command:

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -dc <Your Context> --files "Account.AccessDenied"
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=netcore-cli

I hope it helps

Comment: This was the issue for me. Although I just right clicked on the section then => "Add" => "New Scaffolded Item"

Answer (score 1):

You need to add **area = "Identity"** in values parameter.

The final callbackUrl code will look like below:

```
var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                pageHandler: null,
                values: new { area="Identity", userId = userId, code = code },
                protocol: Request.Scheme);
```